# not able to fetch data from NSUrl in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsurl, fetch

i made iPad application, i want to fetch data from this url,

```
http://ipad.idealake.com/stockquote.aspx?id=SBIN
```

and i want to store this data into string,

so i written this, but it doesn't take data into the string,

```
    NSURL *urlq=[NSURL URLWithString:str1];
    NSURLRequest *reqq=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlq];
    [webViewq loadRequest:reqq];


mainstr=[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlq encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding error:NULL];  

    NSLog(@"WHOLE STRING=%@",mainstr);
```

output of log is:  WHOLE STRING=NULL

**am i doing any mistake in this code ?**

***Thanks In Advance !!***

Comment: The encoding for that URL is almost certainly *not* UTF-32

Comment: Also please don't enter NULL in your error return and post a question. I just ran this code with a valid error object and it clearly states that there is an encoding error (I.e., the URL doesn't return UTF-32 encoded data). Check your errors first, then request help. It's common curtousy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)fire{

NSString *URL = @"http://ipad.idealake.com/stockquote.aspx?id=SBIN";
    NSURLRequest *rq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
    conn1 = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:rq delegate:self];
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [webData setLength: 0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [webData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction");
    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString *theResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"xml : %@",theResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the encoding to `NSUTF8StringEncoding`. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
 NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str1]];
        NSData *myData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *finalRespStr = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

use `NSURLConnection` using JSON web service. it may be help for you [how to download the data from web service](http://geekios.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/how-to-get-data-frm-json-web-service-in-iphone/?preview=true&preview_id=47&preview_nonce=3ffae3342b)